# Calling proc using cx_Oracle and dumping json string

Tags: json, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am trying to dump a json string to oracle and have a procedure to call. However I keep receiving this error

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCTIONNAME'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The procdure has 1 input clob json string and one varchar2 output determining if it succeeded or failed

This is a sample of my code

```
summarylist = {"IDName":OIDText,"FILENAME":filename,"DATA_SUM":data}
print json.dumps(summarylist,ensure_ascii=False)
try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(connectionString)
    cur = con.cursor()

    orcstatus = cur.callproc('testenv.functionname', [json.dumps(summarylist,ensure_ascii=False)])
    print orcstatus

finally:
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

How should I be calling this procedure? Should I be using callfunc instead?

Comment: I suppose you should make the summarylist's value and JSON's individual values quoted as `'{"IDName":"OIDText","FILENAME":"filename","DATA_SUM":"data"}'`

Comment: Include the definition of the PL/SQL procedure. Without that we have no idea what the parameters are!